# How to display Couse & Category list in moodle form?

Tags: moodle

**Hi,**

I want to display course and category list from database in moodle form, as shown below:

Code:

```
class addschedule_form extends moodleform {

    function definition () {
        $mform =& $this->_form;
        $mform->addElement  ( 'date_time_selector', 'date-time', get_string('date-time'));
        $mform->addElement('text', 'category', 'Category');
        $mform->setType('category', PARAM_TEXT);
        $mform->addElement('text', 'course', 'Course');
        $mform->setType('course', PARAM_TEXT);

        $this->add_action_buttons(false, 'submit');
    }

}
```

Any reference or help will be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the category list

```
$options = coursecat::make_categories_list();
$mform->addElement('select', 'categoryid', get_string('coursecategory'), $options);
$mform->setDefault('categoryid', $currentcategoryid);
$mform->setType(PARAM_INT);
```

Courses is tricker. For a list of all courses in the system:

```
$options = array();
$allcourses = coursecat::get(0)->get_courses(array('recursive' = true);
foreach ($allcourses as $course) {
    $options[$course->id] = $course-fullname;
}
$mform->addElement('select', 'courseid', get_string('course'), $options);
$mform->setDefault('courseid', $currentcourseid);
$mform->setType(PARAM_INT);
```

For courses for a particular category

```
 $catcourses = coursecat::get($currentcategoryid)->get_courses();
```

Comment: It's not working, do i have to include course config?

Comment: can you show the full code for the form or is that it? if so you need to add this at the top - require_once ($CFG->libdir.'/formslib.php');
- also if you are not using $currentcategoryid or $currentcourseid then remove the setDefault lines

Comment: i am able to insert data in database table, but without category and course. I'll share the code soon.

Comment: Hi @Russell, i am facing error in this line of code $allcourses = coursecat::get(0)->get_courses(array('recursive' = true);